# TGIFImage with animated GIF - events are not working - how to detect animation progress?

Tags: delphi, tgifimage

Delphi's `TGIFImage` has the following events: `OnPaint`, `OnAfterPaint`, `OnLoop`, `OnEndPaint`.
But none of this events are ever called while displaying animated GIF.

I use the following code to display animated GIF:

```
  FGif := (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage);
  FGif.OnProgress := GifProgress;
  FGif.OnLoop := GifLoop;
  FGif.OnPaint := GifPaint;
  FGif.OnEndPaint := GifEndPaint;
  FGif.OnAfterPaint := GifAfterPaint;
  FGif.Animate := True;
```

How to extract the current visible frame index when animation is playing?

How to detect when animation is finished?

How to detect when the next frame is going to be displayed?

`OnProgress` event is called only during first animation loop, after last animation frame is drawn - TGIFImage will continue animation from the first frame, but this event stops working.

I am using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Comment: If you have access to the source, you could do some debugging to find out why the events are not called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the events you mention are not (as you have discovered) implemented, although the placeholders are there. It seems they have been missing from about a decade ago when a major modification was made to the `GifImg` unit.

With another approach you can however solve the issues you mention. That is to declare the `TGIFRenderer` separately, which gives you access to needed information.

A sample application looks like this:

```
type
  TForm22 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    OpenDlg: TOpenDialog;
    SaveDlg: TSaveDialog;
    Image1: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    r: TRect;
    gif: TGifImage;
    rend: TGIFRenderer;
    procedure GifChange(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

implementation


procedure TForm22.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not OpenDlg.Execute() then Exit;

  // the following is 12 by default to be as slow as Mozilla in last millenium
  GIFDelayExp := 10; // set to 10 for correct timing

  gif:= TGIFImage.Create;
  gif.LoadFromFile(OpenDlg.FileName);
  gif.OnChange := GifChange;

  r := Rect(0, 0, Gif.Width, Gif.Height);
  r.offset((Image1.Width-Gif.Width) div 2, (Image1.Height-Gif.Height) div 2);

  rend := TGIFRenderer.Create(Gif);
  rend.Animate := True;
  rend.StartAnimation;
  rend.Draw(Image1.Canvas, r);

  //Set animate to true at the end, otherwise an exception at address will be raised.
  gif.Animate := True;
end;

procedure TForm22.GifChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  rend.Draw(Image1.Canvas, r);

  Label1.Caption := Format('Frame nr %d / %d',[rend.FrameIndex, gif.Images.Count]);
  Label2.Caption := Format('Per frame: %d ms',[rend.FrameDelay]);
  Label3.Caption := Format('Full cycle: %d s',[rend.FrameDelay * gif.Images.Count]);
end;
```

With the `TGifRenderer.FrameIndex`, `TGifImage.Images.Count` and `TGifRenderer.FrameDelay` you can calculate the answers to your questions.